# When is multi process application is better than multi thread application in a single machine?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, operating-system

I was asked below two questions in an software engineer interview but could not answer. I did goggle search but could not find answer.

a. When is multi process application is better than multi thread application in a single machine?
b. When is multi thread not possible in a single machine but multi process is possible?

Comment: When you're a Firefox author and you can't keep it from crashing so you split it up into 20 processes.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few situations where multiple processes might be better than a single multi-threaded process:

1. If you want to parallelize some software that wasn't designed to run (well) in multiple threads in a single process.  (Two examples would be the Python interpreter whose GIL limits multithreaded performance, and GUI toolkits like Qt that require all GUI widgets to live in a single thread)
2. If you're worried that the software might crash or corrupt data and want to limit the scope of the damage that occurs if/when that happens.  (if one of the threads of a multithreaded program goes awry, it can and usually does affect/corrupt/crash all of the threads in the process; OTOH if a process crashes, the other processes will not be directly affected)
3. If you want your software to be able to recover from a crash.  That's nearly impossible to do in a single-process program, but with multiple processes you can have a parent "babysitter" process that watches for when its children crash or exit and responds by re-launching them when necessary.
4. If you want to make sure your threads don't spy on each other.  (For example, you might have a program being used by multiple unrelated users at once, and you want to make sure that user A's private data can't possibly get "leaked" to user B -- keeping the users' data in separate processes would go a long way towards enforcing that restriction)
5. If you want your threads/processes to run with different levels of privilege.  In a multiprocess model, you can have different processes running as different users with different access levels; whereas in a single multithreaded process, all threads will be running as the same user and therefore have the same privileges/permissions as each other.

As for when a multithreaded process is not possible:  the only scenario I can think of is in an (old) OS that doesn't support multi-threaded programs, but does support multiple processes.  Many of the more ancient variants of Unix were like that.

Answer (score 2):

> Q1. When multi thread is not possible in a single machine but multi process is possible?

A1:

- When the operating system kernel does not support native threads and the application's runtime doesn't implement "green threads".  (Research the terms "native thread" and "green thread".)
- When the application itself is single-threaded.  (Research the terms "single-threaded" and "multi-threaded" in the context of application design and implementation.)  Applications need to be *written* to be multi-threaded.

> Q2: When is multi process application is better than multi thread application in a single machine?

A2:

- When the language's implementation of multi-threading cannot effectively use multiple cores.  For example, research the problem of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) in some Python implementations.
- When the programmer doesn't have the concurrent programming skills needed to develop a multi-threaded program.  For example, a typical undergraduate course in Java doesn't go into the level of detail needed to really understand Java concurrent programming.

There are other "whens" that apply in more specific scenarios.

---

Note that writing a single-threaded application is easier than writing a multi-threaded one, so it may be easier to use multiple processes instead of multiple threads.  But that not about what is **possible**, or even necessarily **better**.  These things are highly context dependent.  The depend on the program, the language, the skills of the developer and so on.

And there are definitely scenarios where multi-threading can give a better solution than multiple processes despite all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-process is better than multi-threaded when you need to isolation that processes provide to prevent tasks from interfering with each other or the controlling process.  This can mean, for example:

1. You want to be able to terminate tasks abruptly.  If they are processes, then the OS will ensure that their system resources are released; or
2. You just want to be sure that a task's resources are freed when it completes, even if it completes normally; or
3. You have a (non-adversarial) multi-tenant system; or
4. You want to be sure that tasks do not inadvertently share memory, etc.

I'm not sure what the asker wants w.r.t. multi-threading being "impossible", but maybe he is thinking of one of the above scenarios, or just when you're using a host environment like NodeJS that doesn't allow multi-threading.